# How to sort an array in descending and ascending in php?

Tags: php

I have an array composed of a GPA and student's age all in a Student class. I have to sort the GPA in descending order, then the age in ascending in case two students have the same GPA.

This is the student class:

```
class Student
{
    private $gpa;
    private $age;
    public function __construct($gpa, $age)
    {
        $this->gpa = $gpa;
        $this->age = $age;
    }
    public function getGPA()
    {
        return $this->gpa;
    }
    public function getAge()
    {
        return $this->age;
    }
}
```

So far, I tried creating two functions in the student's class:

```
public function gpaRange() {
        return rsort($gpa);
}

public function ageRage() {
        return sort($age);
}
```

Comment: To be sure about the problem: are `$gpa` and `$age` two arrays, where each index is referring to the same student?

Comment: Could you please show us some example values of what is in these arrays? Also what does it have to do with PHP 7?

Comment: so from my understanding of the question I have an array of student objs in Student, which is gpa and age. So yes each index is referring to the same student ex, Student 1 gpa will be 4.0 and they're 22 years old, student 2 3.5 and 19 years old, and so on.

Also for the php7 tag please don't mind that, i must've added it along with the php tag accidentally

Comment: *"so from my understanding of the question"* Are you saying this is not your question? Could you show us the value of `$gpa` and `$age` being passed to the constructor. I have a feeling that these are not arrays.

Comment: This is all the information I was given from the question, sorry.

Comment: What question? You are the one asking a question! You have all the details, which is why we ask YOU for clarifications.

Comment: If you have an array of student objects, that mean each `Student` have a GPA and an age (both are scalar), which is quite logical. Therefore, you can use a custom sort: `usort($students, function (Student $a, Student $b) { return $a->getGPA() <=> $b->getGPA() || $b->getAge() <=> $a->getAge(); });`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use usort () with its own compare function to sort an array of student class objects.

```
$sortFctGpaAge = function($a, $b){
  $cmp = $b->getGPA() <=> $a->getGPA();  //desc
  if($cmp == 0) $cmp = $a->getAge() <=> $b->getAge(); //asc 
  return $cmp;
};

usort($students,$sortFctGpaAge);
```

Note the order of the arguments in the comparisons for descending and ascending sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution which utilizes bubble sort, first on the GPAs descending, then after finding groups of multiple GPAs, on the ages ascending.  Warning:  It's a slightly long solution, and a little ugly (everyone, feel free to simplify my answer).

I've also included a larger array to test it.

```
class Student
{
    private $gpa;
    private $age;
    public function __construct($gpa, $age)
    {
        $this->gpa = $gpa;
        $this->age = $age;
    }
    public function getGPA()
    {
        return $this->gpa;
    }
    public function getAge()
    {
        return $this->age;
    }
}


$students = 
    array(new Student(4.0,22),
          new Student(3.3,21),
          new Student(2.7,22),
          new Student(3.4,19),
          new Student(3.6,22),
          new Student(4.0,20),
          new Student(3.0,21),
          new Student(3.0,19),
          new Student(3.0,20));

foreach ($students as $a)
{
    echo $a->getGPA().", ".$a->getAge()."<br>";
}

echo "<br>";


//First, sort by GPA descending using bubble sort.
$sorted = false;
while ($sorted == false)
{
    $sorted = true;
    for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($students) - 1; $x++)
    {

        //Clear temporary array.
        $temp_array = array();

        //Compare the current entry and the one right after it.
        //If in the wrong, order populate the temporary array to re-enter the values in the main array.
        if ($students[$x]->getGPA() < $students[$x+1]->getGPA())
        {
            $temp_array[0] = $students[$x+1];
            $temp_array[1] = $students[$x];

            $students[$x] = $temp_array[0];
            $students[$x+1] = $temp_array[1];
            $sorted = false;
        }
    }

    //The loop continues until all GPA entries are sorted. 
}



//Secondly, sort by age.
$counter = 0;
$target_gpa = 0;
$indices = array();
while ($counter < sizeof($students))
{
    if ($target_gpa == 0)
    {
        $target_gpa = $students[$counter]->getGPA();
        array_push($indices, $counter);
    }
    else 
    {
        if ($students[$counter]->getGPA() == $target_gpa)
        {
            array_push($indices, $counter);
        }
        else if ($students[$counter]->getGPA() != $target_gpa and sizeof($indices) < 2)
        {
            $indices = array();
            $target_gpa = $students[$counter]->getGPA();
            array_push($indices, $counter);
        }
        else if ($students[$counter]->getGPA() != $target_gpa and sizeof($indices) > 1 or $students[$counter]->getGPA() == $target_gpa and $counter + 1 == sizeof($students)- 1)
        {
            if ($counter + 1 == sizeof($students) - 1)
            {
                array_push($indices, $counter + 1);
            }

            //Bubble sort.
            $sorted = false;
            while ($sorted == false)
            {
                $sorted = true;
                for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($indices) - 1; $x++)
                {

                    //Clear temporary array.
                    //$temp_array = array();

                    //Compare the current entry and the one right after it.
                    //If in the wrong order, populate the temporary array to re-enter the values in the main array.

                    if ($students[$indices[$x]]->getAge() > $students[$indices[$x+1]]->getAge())
                    {
                        //echo "Temp arrays: ".$temp_array[0]->getAge().", ".$temp_array[1]->getAge()."<br>";
                        $temp_array[0] = $students[$indices[$x+1]];
                        $temp_array[1] = $students[$indices[$x]];

                        $students[$indices[$x]] = $temp_array[0];
                        $students[$indices[$x+1]] = $temp_array[1];
                        $sorted = false;
                    }
                }

            }

            //Replace the indices array with the new entry.
            $indices = array();
            $target_gpa = $students[$counter]->getGPA();
            array_push($indices, $counter);

        }


    }

    $counter += 1;
}

foreach ($students as $a)
{
    echo $a->getGPA().", ".$a->getAge()."<br>";
}
```